# redirect to file in subdirectory, if exist there

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a '.htaccess' file that contain this code :
(It should to redirect names like "P7-product_number_7")

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# if:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
# then:
RewriteRule ([A-z])([0-9]+)-([^/]*)?$ /cache%{REQUEST_URI}.html [B,L]
# else:
RewriteRule ([A-z])([0-9]+)-([^/]*)?$ index.php?type=$1&id=$2&label=$3 [B,L]
```

The checking of the existing of the file (in 'cache' directory) works fine, but the redirection doesn't works.
***Why ?***

I have tried to use "**RewriteRule  ^(.*)$  /cache/$1.html [L]**" instead the first RewriteRule, but it didn't worked too.
(the redirection if HTML file don't exist (in /cache/) works fine , the '.htaccess' and 'cache/' directory are in the '/var/www' directory, so %{REQUEST_URI} is "/P7-product_number_7")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are looping because you're not checking for the beginning of the URI. You may notice that the `label` **$_GET** param is **product_number_7.html**, with the `.html` at the end. This means the first rule is being applied, then the rules loop, but the second time the first condition fails (because there's no `P7-product_number_7.html.html`) so the second rule gets applied:

1. URI = `/P7-product_number_7`
2. Condition check: `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f` -> true
3. Apply rule: matches `([A-z])([0-9]+)-([^/]*)?$` -> true
4. URI rewritten to `/cache/P7-product_number_7.html`
5. start URI `/P7-product_number_7` != `/cache/P7-product_number_7.html`, rewrite engine loops:

   1. URI = `/cache/P7-product_number_7.html`
   2. Condition check: `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f` -> **false** (`/cache/cache/P7-product_number_7.html.html` doesn't exist)
   3. Apply rule: matches `([A-z])([0-9]+)-([^/]*)?$` - > true (matches the /cache/**P7-product_number_7**.html part of the URI)
   4. URI is rewritten to `/index.php?type=P&id=7&label=product_number_7.html`

So you either need to add a no-more-rewriting passthrough in the beginning of your rules:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Or you can simply match the beginning of the URI in your regex:

```
# need ^ ---v
RewriteRule ^([A-z])([0-9]+)-([^/]*)?$ /cache%{REQUEST_URI}.html [B,L]
# and here -v:
RewriteRule ^([A-z])([0-9]+)-([^/]*)?$ index.php?type=$1&id=$2&label=$3 [B,L]
```